# why wont object pass through from parameter to inside the new thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In the code below when I call `doSomethingCool(x);` I am having an issue where I am unable to get the value of `myco.name`; when it is in side the thread.  How do I pass it into inside the thread?

```
MyCustomObj x = new MyCustomObj();
x.name = "test";


doSomethingCool(x); 


    protected void doSomethingCool(final MyCustomObj myco) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                  //Myco is null  why?
                  String sName = myco.name; ////Why wont the object Myco pass through to here?

            }
        };

        t.start();      
    }
```

Comment: Why is there an empty catch block for `Exception e`? 1) You should never just catch all exceptions. 2) You should atleast output something to indicate that the exception occured.

Comment: What is your problem? It works right here. Can you give us the code of `MyCustomObj`? And please display the stack trace.

Comment: make sure you are initializing properly before caling the method

Comment: You are saying something which is not actually happening, but you say which you think is happening

Comment: If I break point it and add a watch - I can see it as null in side the thread. do you know why?

Comment: The code you are showing works - see http://ideone.com/Ec09xf. Output is `sName=test`, so both `myco` and `myco.name` are not null.

Comment: show some more codes .. the flow of calling the method .. and initializing

Comment: Andreas: would it make a difference if I running it in my android emulato? Thnaks for the help

Comment: First things first: Log the result to make sure it's not just some debugger fluke. Also log it in the method itself to make sure it's nit some normal bug (most likely explanation really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written it correctly. It is the debugger problem.

I have seen such nonsense with debugging very often in Eclipse/Android plugin. Sometimes restart of IDE(eclipse) helped. Sometimes I had to restart the emulator only. Once I had to restart the computer (and it was in Linux!).

Also, put there try/catches and put breakpoints into catches.

Comment: @hello-World Hello, if it is really so, please, edit tags, put there your IDE name (eclipse/netbeans/IntellijIdea...) and debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You might need mark `MyCustomObj.name` as volatile to guarantee that all threads see the same value.

eg:

```
public class MyCustomObj {
    public volatile String name;
}
```

Comment: keeping volatile as variable will not change the object as not null

Comment: I can only assume that the code you're running is different from the code you've provided as it looks like it should work to me.

Comment: There's a happens before relationship when creating a thread so the thread will always see the correct value of all parameters there. No need for volatile

Answer (score 0):

you will have the value of that String. see this code below-

```
public class Exct
{
    Me m=new Me();
    String s;
    public static class Me
    {
        public String ht()
        {
            return "me";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        Exct c=new Exct();
        try
        {
            System.out.println(c.call(c.m)+" in main");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public String call(final Me m) throws Exception
    {

        Thread t=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                s=m.ht();
                System.out.println(s+" in run");

            }
        };
        t.start();
        //System.out.println(s+" in run return ");
        //t.sleep(1);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Here the output is-

null in main
me in run

because when t.start() executes it will search for run method but due to  multithreading feature of java at the same time the return statements executes and null value returned.

now if you would do anything which can wait the thread till the run method executes then the returned value will be accurate. we can do this by opening that print line which null but return executes after some time or we can make that thread sleep of even 1 second will do the rest and the output will be-

me in run
me in main

right now i don't have any other explanation, i'll update it when find any other good solution.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, if we need to pass parameters to a thread, we can use either of the two approaches mentioned below:

1. **Create a custom Runnable like this:**

   ```
   public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

   private MyCustomObj obj;

   public MyRunnable( MyCustomObj obj) {

     this.obj = obj;

   }

   public void run() {

     System.out.println("Name:" + obj.name );

   }
   ```

   }

and then

```
MyCustomObj x = new MyCustomObj();
x.name = "test";
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(x));
t.start();
```

2.Create custom thread like below:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

private MyCustomObj obj;

public MyThread( MyCustomObj obj) {

this.obj = obj;

}

public void run() {

System.out.println("Name:" + obj.name );

}
}
```

and then

```
 MyThread t = new MyThread(x);
 t.start();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Or #3 just access a variable in its scope which is exactly what he's doing.